# Prevent marker caching of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I'm presenting a Google Map with custom markers (pins) on it.  The long/lat of the markers is read from a JSON file.  When I update the marker locations in the JSON file, the pin location doesn't update.  I have to go into Chrome Settings and manually clear the cache to get it to update.

I've tried adding the following to the php file that generates the map:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

I tried adding various random parameter values to all the javascript includes in the PHP file (map_functions.js?test=123)

I've searched the Google Maps Javascript API Documentation for any sort of parameter that controls caching but have not found anything useful.  What it looks like is the browser is treating the map like an image and caching it and the headers the API is sending when generating the map have a 1 day expiration.

How can I make sure the changes to the marker locations in the JSON file are displayed when the map page is reloaded without having to constantly clear the browser cache?

Comment: Did you ever consider that it might be the *browser* that's caching the file... and that may be why you found nothing in the maps API docs about it?

Comment: Would you mind creating a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.